# Change the rotation of a cube WebGL

Tags: javascript, rotation

I need to solve a tsk where it is asked to me to simulate the behavior of a dog's tail. This "tale" is a simple cube and I have rotate from 0° to 45° and from 45° to 0°. The problem is that when it arrives at 45° degrees it starts the rotation again from 0°.[image]

I need a constant movement; not restoring the initial position and restart the rotation from 0° to 45°.

```
var theta = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 180, 0, 180, 0, 20, 0];
var tailId = 11;
function move() {
    // TAIL
    var dir = true;
    if ( theta[tailId] < 45  ) {
        theta[tailId] +=1;
    }
    if (theta[tailId] == 45){
        while(theta[tailId] !=45 )theta[tailId]+=-1;}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use the dir variable (which is already specified) but only as an number. When the value exceeds a bound, just invert the direction.

Something like:

```
var theta = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 180, 0, 180, 0, 20, 0];
var tailId = 11;
var dir = 1;

function move() {
    // TAIL
    theta[tailId] += dir;

    if ( theta[tailId] < 0  ) {
        theta[tailId] = 0;
        dir = -dir;
    } else
     if ( theta[tailId] > 45  ) {
        theta[tailId] = 45;
        dir = -dir;
    } 
}
```

---

You might try it with a sinus function. Looks better...

```
var theta = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 180, 0, 180, 0, 20, 0];
var tailId = 11;
var phase = 0;
var step = 0.1;

function move() {
    // TAIL

    // convert from -1..1  =>  0..45
    theta[tailId] = 22.5 + (Math.sin(phase) * 22.5);
    phase += step;
}
```